# My file that has been locked because of a thread and it is not being terminated by even after aborting it

Tags: multithreading, abort

I tried to abort the thread and delete a file but the file still gives me the message saying it is used by another process. After aborting the thread it keeps on going through the catch block and I saw a document in Microsoft that says to avoid it from going to end of every catch block if you perform reset.Abort , the abort process will be cancelled, that means the file will still have a process that is using it. Is there a way I can abort my thread before closing the application and delete a file?
                      if(!task.IsCompleted)
                    {

```
                    Thread t1 = Thread.CurrentThread;

                    if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null)
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Action_Thread";
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        t1.Abort("Aborted");
                    }
                    catch(ThreadAbortException ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Thread now being aborted");
                    }
               File.Delete("somefile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Most platforms only automatically close file handles when processes exit, not individual threads, so you have to close or unlock the file (or its handle) before aborting the thread.

How this would be done, and whether it can be done automatically on thread abort or requires the abort logic to explicitly call the close operation, depends on which platform or language environment you are using.

Comment: I am using c# and running on windows.

Comment: @SarbeshBanskota don't use thread.Abort as it will not release managed resources. Send a message or set a volatile flag that the thread checks so it can exit gracefully.

Comment: I am not sure how that process is done, so far the process of aborting the thread and deleting the file is added above with the description.

Comment: @SarbeshBanskota there is no reason to abort the current thread using thread.Abort(). Simply return from the thread's run method or throw an exception.

Comment: What I am trying to do is if the process gets stuck in some action which in my case it is, I just want to delete that thread and get the file released taken by that action, that is the reason why I was trying to abort the thread. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @SarbeshBanskota you might get away with opening the file, spawning the thread, joining it, and aborting it on timeout if the thread doesn't use any other resources, but more probably you'll have to abort the process instead.

Comment: I have tried using that method as well, killing the process will solve it, but the thing is, the process I am using a different process. I am trying to release the file without killing the process so I thought of aborting the thread. I am have been looking for a way to release the file locked by the process without killing the process. Please let me know what you might think about it.

Comment: @SarbeshBanskota you should ask a new, better question, showing the method you are trying to abort, and justify why you cannot just return early or throw an exception when whatever issue you are trying to avoid occurs.